# javascript - what is fs and how do I install it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm new to javascript and I think this is a very basic question but I cannot find the answer.  I am developing some javascript code and I want to use sql.js but it is failing on the line

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

which I'm sure it because *fs* is not installed.  I have found load of hits relating to *fs*, but I am no closer to understanding what it is or how to install it.

Comment: Could you provide some code? which sql.js are you using?

Comment: It's a built-in nodejs library: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html You don't have to install anything. Can you tell us how do you run your code?

Comment: Stab in the dark: you're not actually using Node.js, but you're developing **Javascript for the browser**...!?

Answer (score 1):

It is an integral part of [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system), so it should be already available for you. Make sure you are running your script on Node.

Comment: My mistake, I had picked up an example that used node.  I will research some more.  Thanks for your help